# A KOOL rebus puzzle

Tags: rebus

What does this rebus mean?

## 12356789 KOOL

---

**Hint #1:**

> The answer has to do partly with the fact the 4 is MISSING, not JUST that the 4 is special itself.

**Hint #2:**

> The phrase "look back" is correct and is in the answer. (Obviously it's not the entire answer though) You also have to be a bit creative with the whole number thing. Happy guessing!

Comment: Would I have to get "creative" with my spelling to get the answer?

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: Hard to describe exactly what I mean. What I see in this rebus makes me think of four words, where if you mash the first two together, they sound *kind of* like a different word, which works with the remaining word to make the answer. Does that make sense?

Comment: I understand but I don't think you're thinking of what the answer is.

Comment: Missing numbers are KOOL and the phrase has 12 letters. 12 is divisible by 3. Half Life 3 confirmed!

Comment: @Irishpanda *Gasp* DUN DUN DUNNNN!

Comment: I added some hints to help! :D

Answer (score 8, accepted):

OK, I'm *prrrrrrrretty sure* this isn't the answer, but in the spirit of the site, this is what I was getting at in my comment on the OP:

> Never look back

because

> given absurdly liberal leeway in pronunciation, "no four" sounds kinda almost a little but not really but just enough like "never"

Comment: Oh, well then... You evidently got it correct! Good job, we have a winner! I wouldn't really call it ABSURD pronunciation... It's not like I made "Hello" into "Her Law" or something. If it's too easy then ya know, everyone will solve it in 1 minute, but if it's too hard, you got a problem that's honestly taking like a month or longer to solve, and... You know... But anyways this just popped up in my head and I thought I'd post it on the site. Hope you enjoyed it! :D

Comment: @Xandawesome: Too much of a leap IMO. They don't sound remotely alike to me.

Comment: @Xandawesome I have to agree that it is absurdly liberal; in fact your example ("hello > her law") seems slightly less liberal.

Comment: Well I'm sorry that you feel that way, but in my mind it sounds perfectly fine: "No4 ==> Nofer ==> F sounds kinda like V ==> Nover ==> Never"

Comment: @Xandawesome I had considered this answer, but determined that there was no way that you could expect anyone to get "never" from "no four", so I never posted it.

Comment: Except 4 isn't pronounced /fə(ɹ)/ or /fɜː(ɹ)/ or anything, it's /fɔː/ or /fo(ː)ɹ/.

Comment: @OrangeDog ...by you, in your dialect.

Comment: Sorry, I just wanted to post a rebus riddle I thought of and I didn't know the answer wouldn't be good, sorry... I can see, though, how it's not that good, the pronunciation is kind of- off, I guess you could say.

Comment: @Xandawesome I personally don't think it's as big a deal as others are making it out to be. At least the answer to this one is a common phrase - I've seen a number of """rebuses""" here that just seem to be arbitrary sentences.

Comment: @question_asker I can see someone saying "Okay, the answer is one too many is a big elephant on the roof of the keyboard pond that flies on a boaty boat when the beaver king comes to feast on the giant grand apple!" Eh? Ehhh...?

Answer (score 14):

I'll take a stab:

> "Look back, it's a foregone (4 gone) conclusion"

Comment: No, but you're getting closer!

Comment: I love how I got the Nice Answer badge for one that isn't even correct, lol!

Answer (score 9):

Just a guess...

> Look back, not forward.

Comment: I bet that's the closest yet, just not sure where the -ward would come from.

Comment: Like Irishpanda guessed, this is the closest so far! You're really close!

Comment: The only other thing I can thing of is "Never look back".  If you slur your words, "no four" sounds kinda like "never"..........

Comment: @APrough this is the answer I was getting at in my comment on the OP!

Comment: @question_asker, you should put it as an answer.

Comment: @APrough done. Seems like it can't possibly be right, but I might as well go down fighting.

Answer (score 6):

Maybe it is

> Look back, not foreseen

Comment: Good twist on the missing 4, didn't think of that one.

Answer (score 4):

Is it

> Number School
> because there are a bunch of "numbers" + "kool" and put together "Numberskool" -> "Number-skool" -> "number-school"

After second hint:

> Look back, for numbers are left. (Four has left and the numbers are to the left side of look back.)

Comment: No, but nice try!

Comment: Is the missing "4" intentional?

Comment: Yep! It definitely is!

Answer (score 4):

might the answer be

> "Not four Skool"

Comment: No, that's not it, but welcome to puzzling!

Answer (score 4):

Is it

> foregone conclusion?

Because

> The four is missing from the count, 4 gone->foregone 
> and KOOL is look backwards -> lookback which is a synonym for conclusion

*After Second Hint*

Is it

> Look back for missing numbers?

Answer (score 3):

Some guesses:

- *Not* *Look*ing forward to
- *Look* be*fore* you leap
- *Look* forward to
- *Look*ing *back* *for* ______

In decreasing order of plausibility

Answer (score 2):

Guess

> Before Count foregone his look back

Explanation

> Before (It happens 'before' kool) Count (Meaning count Dracula or sesame street count, because 12356789 is counting) foregone (meaning given up -- because the four is gone from the list) look back (meaning remember or recall)  So, "Before the Count has given up on thinking of the past"

Answer (score 2):

Is it

> Count forward, look back

Because

> You're counting in order without a four; and look is reversed

Answer (score 2):

I'm gussing

> go forth before look back

Explanation

> four is gone so gone forth, or go forth, and look is backward so look back. and 12356789 is before kool, hence my answer.

Comment: Nice try, everyone is really close!

Answer (score 2):

Is it?

> Look back for nothing then

Because

> Look is reversed and the number 4 is not in the 10 numbers

Comment: I see eight numbers, even with 4 that would be nine numbers. Unless you are counting the eight numbers and the O's in KOOL? I'm assuming you were using "Ten" as "Then" in your answer?